# Updating 3d model respecting existing material

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm constantly updating a 3D Architectural model, via external software, and importing into blender to render with cycles. I have one scene fully setup, materials, cameras, environment etc.
Here's my question: How could I import the modified scene into the old one (e.g walls of a room changing their shape) and respecting the old materials that I've set up. I'm importing  obj objects. What I'm doing is duplicating all the materials, which is pretty repetitive to re-assigned every material every time.

Comment: Are the objects named, with "meaningful" names? I.e., not just "Plane.001" or something?

Comment: That's right, when I import the new mesh, names are something such as "mesh305 Group 3 Ceiling". But my problem is that the imported mesh is duplicating all the materials, even they already have same orignal name. ie Wood light. Would import for second time as Wood light_1 and with the second importing wood light_2...